# Python syntax if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I currently have

```
seq1 = "--MFA"
seq2= "--MFU"

for i in range(0, len(seq1)):

    if seq1[i] or seq2[i] == '-':

        print  "hi"
    else:
        print "bye"
```

Why does it print "hi" 5 times (even if seq1[i] and seq1[i] are M, F, A/U). I thought it was a regex problem at first, but even escaping the hyphen yielded the same results.

Comment: When in doubt, use the REPL (IDLE or in the shell) and type. `'-' or '2' >>> '-'` `'-' or '2' == '-' >>> '-'` So you can guess that it always return the left part because it's interpreted as True.

Answer (score 3):

`if seq1[i] or seq2[i] == '-':`

Means:

`if (seq1[i]) or (seq2[i] == '-'):`

If `seq[i]` has a value of `True` (i.e, if `bool(seq1[i]) == True`), then the conditional statement will instantly be true, because of the `or`. With an `or` operator, if one side is `True`, then the conditional runs.

Note that `bool(seq1[i])` will **always be True** because a string with any length is considered True.

Hence, `'hi'` is printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
if seq1[i] or seq2[i] == '-':
```

This condition means that if `seq1[i]` is true or `seq2[i] = '-'` do the following. In that case, seq1[i] is true the 5 times. Then, it prints 'hi' 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of alternatives you could use here

```
if '-' in (seq1[i], seq2[i]):
```

Is concise, but is funny to read.

```
if seq1[i] == '-' or seq2[i] == '-':
```

Feels more natural

A cleaner way to loop through the sequences together is to use `zip`

```
for i, j in zip(seq1, seq2):

    if i == '-' or j == '-':
        print  "hi"
    else:
        print "bye"
```

If you were looping through more sequences together, a good way to extend the comparison is to use `any`

```
for item in zip(seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, ...):
    if any(i == '-' for i in item):
        print  "hi"
    else:
        print "bye"
```